# Facebook like/share content locker

Tags: facebook, locking, share, facebook-like

I was looking at stackoverflow the answer and the closest one was "Check if user liked page"

What I want to do is not to check if someone liked, but unlock contend when someone like/share. I dont want to check everytime if someone already like it and then decide to show him content. Everytime someone is visiting mine site I want him to share it again. It can be done without facebook aplication. As expample I can provide this link:

http://strefavideo.pl/?videos=wepchnal-go-pod-pociag-zobacz-jak-to-sie-skonczylo

As you can see, there is an video, which you can watch ONLY if you share by clicking "udostępnij" and than confirming this share.

If I'm wrong and there already is topic like this at stackoverflow than Im sorry and plz lead me to it. If there isnt one, than plz help me :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using wordpress this is the best plugin to you: http://codecanyon.net/item/advanced-facebook-content-locker/1506489. I'm using it for my [free mp3 download](http://www.mp3is.com) site